# How to get all paths from this graph ? Recursive?

Tags: c#, graph, recursive-datastructures

I have set of datas :

```
Point x = somepoint;

Point Y = somepoint;

List<Point> via1 = [1A, 1B, 1C];

List<Point> via2 = [2A, 2B, 2C, 2D];

...

List<Point> vian = [nA, nB, nC];
```

Visualized graph like this (as above, it can expand to n layers) :

[image]

And I want to get all possible path as result like this :

```
List<List<Point> [
    List<Point> [x, 1A, 2A, y]
    List<Point> [x, 1A, 2B, y]
    List<Point> [x, 1A, 2C, y]
    List<Point> [x, 1A, 2D, y]
    List<Point> [x, 1B, 2A, y]
    ...
    List<Point> [x, 1C, 2D, y]
]
```

What is the best way to do it ? 
Need a graph library or some recursive func or just few line of linq ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `via1` fully connected with `via2` and `X` and `via2` fully connected with `Y` all you need ia s loop like this:

```
IEnumerable<Point[]> GetPathSet() 
{
    foreach(var v1 in via1)
        foreach (var v2 in via2)
            yield return new Point[] { X, v1, v2, Y}; 
}
```

If you need to reuse the collection just transform it to an array or to a list, like this: `GetPathSet().ToArray()`.

**UPD:** If you need `n` layers where `n` is not predefined you can expand it like this:

```
IEnumerable<List<Point>> GetPathSet(Point X, Point Y, params List<Point>[] layers)
{
    int[] layerindexes = new int[layers.Length];
    while (true)
    {
        var Path = new List<Point>();

        Path.Add(X);
        for (int i = 0; i < layers.Length; i++)
            Path.Add(layers[i][layerindexes[i]]);
        Path.Add(Y);

        for (int i = layers.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            layerindexes[i]++;
            if (layerindexes[i] >= layers[i].Count)
            {
                layerindexes[i] = 0;
                if (i == 0) yield break;
            }
            else break;
        }

        yield return Path;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the picture, where all points of a nth layer are connected with all points of (n+1) layer, all you need is get Cartesian product of the "via" lists.

If number of "via' lists is predefined, simple nested loops can be used:

```
var allWays = new List<List<Point>>() 
foreach(var v1 in via1)
  foreach (var v2 in via2)
    ...
      foreach (var vn in vian)           
        allWays.Add(new Point[] { X, v1, v2,..., vn, Y});
```

or you can use linq:

```
var allWays = 
    from v1 in vai1
    from v2 in vai2
    ...
    from vn in vain
    select new [] {x, v1, v2, ..., vn, y};
```

However, if you need single function, which will work for any layers count, initial data needs to be presented as List of Lists and the code will look like:

```
List<List<Point>> graphData; //all layers, where the first list contains x, the last one - y

IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Point>> allWays = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<Point>() };
foreach (var layer in graphData)
{
    var l = layer; 
    allWays =
              from w in allWays
              from item in l
              select w.Concat(new[] { item });
}
```

Comment: You have forgotten about `X` and `Y` in the last snippet :)

Comment: Nope, :) they are there in graphData list. The first element of the list is a list, which contains single elemet - x. The last element - y. See comment ;)

Comment: I found typo in ´graphData´ name, which I fixed. However, I am not sure I can see any issues with the comment. Anyway, this comment is not for compiler. :)